# How Ros program work in Linux kernel system?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are Ros program system program or application program??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350495/how-ros-program-work-in-linux-kernel-system??/) by [anonymous53964](https://answers.ros.org/users/53964/anonymous53964/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-04-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's all straightforward user space processes.

There is no support to create ROS nodes as kernel modules/drivers.

I also don't believe that would be something you'd use ROS for.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pring](https://answers.ros.org/users/41927/pring/) on 2020-04-25**:
To add, ROS is not an OS!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-25**:
Well. That's being said more and more, but I guess it depends on how you define "OS". If an OS would be a collection of software and services which allow you to make use of specific hardware and the functionality of that hardware, and if the hardware would be / include robots and related electromechanical systems, it wouldn't be so strange to call ROS an "OS".

Sure, it would not be something you'd run Word on, and it doesn't include code to implement a interrupt based, round-robin process schedular or page-based virtual memory, but neither do some of the "cloud OS" these days.

**Comment by [anonymous53964](https://answers.ros.org/users/53964/anonymous53964/) on 2020-04-27**:
Thank u helped me!!

**Comment by [anonymous53964](https://answers.ros.org/users/53964/anonymous53964/) on 2020-04-29**:
Then how threads are scheduled don't they need that also why publisher and subscriber nodes run in different terminal

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-29**:
ROS nodes are regular Linux/Windows/OSX processes, so the scheduler of the underlying OS will take care of providing scheduling services.

**Comment by [anonymous53964](https://answers.ros.org/users/53964/anonymous53964/) on 2020-05-01**:
Oh...now I understood thanks!!

**Comment by [anonymous53964](https://answers.ros.org/users/53964/anonymous53964/) on 2020-05-01**:
Hi, just another question can u please explain the filesystem structure in ROS ? please

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-01**:
No, I won't do that in this question.

This is not a forum, but a Q&A site like Stack Overflow. You should not post (random) questions as comments under already answered other questions. That's not how this works.

You should post a new question -- after having made sure your question is not already answered by another post here on ROS Answers.

**Comment by [anonymous53964](https://answers.ros.org/users/53964/anonymous53964/) on 2020-05-01**:
Okay sorry,can I know the difference between thread and nodelet. Are both same or different, if so how underlying OS manages it

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-01**:
That would also be a new question, and I'm almost certain that question has been answered here on ROS Answers as well.

Try to search using Google: append `site:answers.ros.org` to your query.